# How to find out if DropBox app folder exists on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, dropbox-api

I am using DropboxSDK in my app. In that am using kDBRootAppFolder so if am using it first time it will create folder with app name. So i want to find if the folder exists or not how can i? is there any method exists in that? if any one have idea please let me know.

Actually am getting Warning like this:

> [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/metadata/sandbox - Token is disabled or invalid while trying to loadData  using :[[self dbClient] loadMetadata:@"/"]; statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about whether your app folder exists or not, exactly. When the user first links, the folder will get created, as you noted. If the folder is removed or the user unlinks the app (e.g. via https://www.dropbox.com/account/applications ) you'll get a 401 error (per the docs https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api ) which you should catch and then prompt the user to relink your app.

Comment: Thanks @Greg. Yes exactly, if i relink it programmatically am able to link it again. But if i remove the folder from my account am getting the above warning but where to handle that? means in which method i can able to handle that error?

Comment: DBSessionDelegate callback - (void)sessionDidReceiveAuthorizationFailure:(DBSession *)session userId:(NSString *)userId